# Convert a Text to an Array - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

im learning PostgreSQL and i encountered a little Problem.

I have a text like this:

```
'{1,1}'
```

and want to create an Array that holds my two values, so that i can access them. 
How do i do that ? 
I tried

```
SELECT string_to_array('{1,1}', '{', '}', ',');
```

But that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`'{1,1}'` can be casted to an array directly:

```
select '{1,1}'::int[]
```

Comment: Thank you ! But how can i access the values now ?

Comment: @Tony94: see here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING